# How to submit form when have input type="submit" inner form using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

How to submit form when have input type="submit" inner form using javascript ?

i want to submit form using javascript (have input type="submit" inner form ).

i tried to use this code

```
<form action="" method="post" name="test_fn">
    <input type="text" name="input1" value="ON">            
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="ON">          
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function(){test_fn.submit();}, 0);
</script>
```

but not work. how can i do that ? for submit form using javascript (have input type="submit" inner form )

thank

Comment: give id="test_fn" and then change your function with document.getElementById("test_fn"). @mongmong seesee

Comment: @RuchishParikh — That's best practise, but won't make any practical difference here.

Comment: what do you mean? @Quentin Have you checked in google? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp

Comment: @RuchishParikh — Have you read the question? Have you tested the code in the question? Have you noticed the effects of putting an input named `submit` in a form has on the `submit` property of the form (i.e. what the question is asking about)? Have you read the comments on Danyal's answer? Have you looked at the duplicate question?

Answer (score -1):

First you should change your `input submit name`.

> > When you name the button submit, you override the submit() function on the form,so it will become "submit is not a function"

```
<form action="" method="post" name="test_fn" id="test_fn">
    <input type="text" name="input1" value="ON">            
    <input type="submit" name="btnsubmit" value="ON"> //Changed submit name here         
</form>
```

then can call submit by your form name like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  setTimeout(function(){document.test_fn.submit()}, 0);
</script>
```

Comment: That won't work. `submit` is not a function.

Comment: what do you mean by not a function? @Quentin Can you please explain?

Comment: Since the form contains a form control with the name `submit`, `reference_to_the_form.submit` will be that form control and not the function it usually is. Changing the way you get a reference to the form won't change that. That's the whole point of the question.

Comment: you are right but .submit is a function in js that does submit the form too. I just told him about using JS method that does submit the form. His logic, requirements and need would be definitely different

Comment: `submit` **was** a function, it has been overwritten. That's the point of the question. The logic needs to change (and the question is asking how) the requirements and need don't need to change.

Comment: does that really matter? If i create onclick event out of the form somewhere else of the page. I can still submit the form using this function..isn't that so? they can be used simultaneously.

Comment: "does that really matter?" — Yes!

Comment: "If i create onclick event out of the form somewhere else of the page. I can still submit the form using this function..isn't that so?" — No! If you could then the OP wouldn't have asked the question!

Comment: I guess I am not getting the context of the question.

Comment: The question is entirely self contained and serves to demonstrate the entire problem. No additional context is required.

Comment: Sorry by we can submit forms even if we declare submit button in the forms.

I have done it before. Please paste this code in a html file and run this



<html>

<head>
<script>

function submitForm(){
alert("Submitting the form");
 document.getElementById("myForm").submit(); 
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<form action="data.php" method="post" id="myForm">

<input type="submit" value="Form submit"/>

</form>

<button onclick="submitForm()">Button to submit form</button>
</body>



</html>

Comment: `<input type="submit" value="Form submit"/>` — That doesn't have `name="submit"` which the code in the question does have. Since it doesn't have `name="submit"` it doesn't overwrite the value of the `submit` property, so of course that works. You moved the goalposts.

Comment: thanks for clarification. Appreciate it, never came across this situation as I usually don't give names to the submit buttons. Strange it is!